# Read double numbers from unknown array dimensions in txt file

Tags: c#, arrays

I need to change the code to know dimension of array in a txt file , the problem in my code that I can get only dimensions of 2d arrays such as 2*2 , 3*3... but I need for example 3*1

```
static double[,] ParseNumberFile(string filename)
{
    // read data from txt file 

    string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(filename);

    // first put all lines into an string array
    string[] allLines = fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // calculate 2D array's dimension lengths, and initialize the 2Darray

    int rowCount = allLines.Length;
    int columnCount = allLines.Length;

    int i = 0, j = 0;
    double[,] result = new double[rowCount, columnCount];
    foreach (var row in fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        j = 0;
        foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
        {
            result[i, j] = double.Parse(col.Trim(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Comment: Note: there's [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx)

Comment: could you please provide some sample Text from your txt?

Answer (score 1):

You could use generic lists:

```
List<List<double>> result = new List<List<double>>();
foreach (var row in fileContent.Split(new char[] { '\t', '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    List<double> list = new List<double>()
    foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
    {
        list.Add(double.Parse(col.Trim(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
    }
    result.Add(list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq way:

```
        double[][] doubles = File.ReadAllLines("foo.txt").
                                  Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)).
                                  Select(line => line.Split(' ').Select(double.Parse).ToArray()).
                                  ToArray();
```

Saves you a lot of code ;)

Comment: Yes, although does not remove empty lines as th OP intended. (`.Where(line=>line.Trim() != "")`) (and I'm not sure why he splits the text by '\t' to find lines (!?))